# Jquery form value confirmation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cordova, validation

Could someone tell me why this comes out as false? I am trying to use similar code for my user authentication system in a Cordova app i am building using jquery mobile to ensure that the password and password confirmation is the same. This data would then be sent over to a php file on my server and then depending on the validation there the php would then return "success" or "failed". Hence, another question i have would be how can i depending on the result returned from the php file can i alter my view on the app? It would be great if someone could suggest me a good way of doing this or a tutorial i could learn from as i am unable to find good tutorials on this as i am new to all this.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#signuppage', function () {
$(document).on('click', '#signupbutton', function () {
    if ($('#confirmpassword').val() === $('#password').val()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/appAuth/profiling.php',
            data: {
                action: 'signup',
                formData: $('#signupform').serialize()
            },
            type:'post',
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                //this is the callback function will trigger before data is sent
                $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
            },
            complete: function () {
                //this is the callback functino will trigger on data sent/received complete
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            },
            success: function (result) {
                resultObject.formSubmitionResult = result;
                $mobile.changePage("#collections");
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                //this is the callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action
                alert('Network error has occured please try again!');
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Please make sure the two passwords match!');
    }
    return false; //cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
});
```

Here is the HTML as requested:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="signuppage" style="background-color:#454545;">
    <div data-role="header" id="head">
        <h1>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left" data-rel="back">Back</a>
            <strong>Signup</strong>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form id="signupform" data-ajax="false">
                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email..." required email>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm password" required equalTo="password">
                </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit" name="signupbutton" id="signupbutton">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qdkawt6n/1/ ?

Comment: Probably because `Firstname` =/= `Lastname` If you enter the same data into both fields it will return TRUE

Comment: Well you had better show us the HTML as well or this Javascript means very little to us

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by; "can i alter my view on the app". On completion of your Ajax request,  what are you trying to alter, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: so i want to create a system where by if the user is not logged in and if he happens to click on a button he would be automatically directed to the log in page and after a successful log in he would be redirected back to where the button would have taken him if he was logged in and at the same time if he didnt have a account he would sign up and that would then lead him to the same page.

Comment: Go do search on "Basic authentication php c#" then create that and come back with a more specific question perhaps?  Frankly, your question as stated is a bit more than confusing in context of your comment.

Comment: Basically lets say if the user clicks on my profile i want to first check if the user is logged in if he is then open up his profile page if he is not redirect him to the login page and after his credentials are authenticated bring him to his profile page. There can also be the case where he is not a user and he then signs up and after signing up is redirected to his profile page.